# How to randomly remove block side in a grid?

Tags: netlogo

Following on from [How to control square size in a grid from square area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107677/how-to-control-square-size-in-a-grid-from-square-area), I would like to randomly remove block side in a grid. Here my idea:

%% In a first time, I randomly select a white patch in the grid (figure below):

```
let random-patch one-of patches with [pcolor = white]
```

%% Then, I draw red patches to identify intersections between white roads (figure below):

```
ask patches with [ (pxcor mod (side + 1) = 0 ) and (pycor mod (side + 1) = 0 ) ] [set pcolor red]
```

%% Finally, I color in brown all white patches that are situated between two red patches and on the same side than the random patch. To identify these white patches, have I to calculate distance between the random patch and the nearest red patches and to color all white patches situated along these distances ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way to think about your problem is in terms of finding clusters of white patches: you're picking a white patch at random, and you want to turn all the *contiguous* white patches to brown.

You can look at the "Patch Clusters Example" in the **Code Examples** section of NetLogo's model library to see one way to do this.

Here is how I would do it. Let's start by defining a `grow-cluster` reporter:

```
to-report grow-cluster [ current-cluster new-patch ]
  let patches-to-add [
    neighbors4 with [
      pcolor = [ pcolor ] of myself and
      not member? self current-cluster
    ]
  ] of new-patch
  let new-cluster (patch-set current-cluster new-patch)
  report ifelse-value any? patches-to-add
    [ reduce grow-cluster fput new-cluster sort patches-to-add ]
    [ new-cluster ]
end
```

The code may be hard to understand if you're not used to functional programming because it uses [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) within a call to [`reduce`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reduce). Still, in a nutshell, it:

- takes an existing patch cluster and a new patch to add to this cluster
- looks for neighbors of that new patch that should also be added to the cluster, i.e., those that are the same color but not already part of the cluster
- calls itself for these new patches to add so that *their* neighbors can be added to the cluster (and those neighbors' neighbors, etc.) until no new patches are found.

Once you have `grow-cluster`, you can use it to accomplish exactly what you want by seeding it with an empty cluster and the random patch that you selected:

```
to remove-random-side
  let random-patch one-of patches with [pcolor = white]
  let side grow-cluster no-patches random-patch
  ask side [ set pcolor brown ]
end
```

Caveat: for this to work, world wrapping has to be disabled in your model settings.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're making a uniform grid, you might consider just doing math on `pxcor` and `pycor` instead of taking the Patch Clusters Example approach. That approach is best suited to dealing with irregular shapes.

To set up your grid, you can just do:

```
ask patches [
  set pcolor brown
  let horizontal-street? pycor mod (side + 1) = 0
  let vertical-street? pxcor mod (side + 1) = 0
  if horizontal-street? or vertical-street?
    [ set pcolor white ]
  if horizontal-street? and vertical-street?
    [ set pcolor red ]
]
```