# How to randomly remove a percentage of block side in a grid?

Tags: netlogo

I seek to randomly remove, for example, 20%, 50%, 80%, ... of block sides in a grid. My idea is :

- to assign a label to each road section by using "Patch Clusters Example"
- then to use the solution from [How to randomly remove block side in a grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261005/how-to-randomly-remove-block-side-in-a-grid) as follows :

  ```
  to remove-random-roads
  let deleted-road-percent 25 
  let road-section-number length remove 0 remove-duplicates ([cluster] of patches)
  let repetition-number (deleted-road-percent * road-section-number) / 100

  repeat repetition-number [
  let random-patch one-of patches with [pcolor = white]
  let side grow-cluster no-patches random-patch
  ask side [ set pcolor brown] ]
  end
  ```

Unfortunately, the code doesn't work because it removes all roads instead of removing 25% of roads in the landscape. I don't understand why it does that ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible explanations:

1. Your computation of how many roads to remove is wrong.
2. Your code for removing the roads is wrong.

So the next step you need to take is figure out which of the two it is.

After `let repetition-number ...`, add:

```
print repetition-number
```

Is the value printed correct? If no, pursue path #1. If yes, pursue path #2. (And if still stuck, come back here and tell us which path you need help with.)